# Split a QString at Tab Space

Tags: c++, string, qt, qstring

How can I split a `QString` at Tab Space?
I have this:

```
QStringList slOut;
                QString str = slOut.at(i);
                strsplit = str.split("\\t");
```

I have also tried `strsplit = str.split("\\t");` but it doesn't work neither...

Comment: Why two back slashes used? What means "does not work"?

Comment: Double backslashes would be when using regular expression, but you don't need that.

Comment: Doesn't work means it doesnt split, it's just doing nothing...

Comment: I don't know, I've just tried it... do you have a solution for me?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add the tab in the split function, without having to use \t.

```
QString input("About to split   Split done"); // tab character between split and Split
QStringList splitList = input.split("   "); // a tab character between the qutoes
```

This produces two strings in the string list "About to Split" and "Split done".

Note that the character in between the quotes of the split function is a tab, not spaces.

Comment: @mc307, have you tried just copying and pasting those two lines, then looking at splitList in a debugger?